# How to solve for nth term in series

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I am making a game, and controlling a character's velocity.

The game works by updating the character's velocity 60 times per second.

At each frame, I do this:

"set new velocity to current velocity + accelerationRate * (maxVelocity - currentVelocity)"

I wrote this out as this series equation (I think that's what this is called, if not please let me know). To simplify I'm using my accelerationRate as .2 and the maxVelocity as 800.

$$a_n = a_{n-1} + .2 * (800 - a_{n-1})$$

So as a series that starts at 0, I'd have:

0, 160, 288, 390.4, 472.32

for my first 5 values.

So I have a few questions:

1. What is my $a_n$ equation called? Is that a "series equation"?
2. How do I solve for the nth term?
3. How do I rewrite this as a sum and/or as an exponential function?

Thanks.. I am really rusty on this.. Sorry for abusing terminology here

Comment: It is a recurrence relation, as columbus says. If you just want the solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%280%29+%3D+0%2C+a%28n%29+%3D+a%28n-1%29+%2B+0.2%28800-a%28n-1%29%29

Comment: I think it's a "recurrence relation." I think you can rewrite that as $a_n=.8a_{n-1}+160$, if I've done the math right. Wolfram Alpha gives $800(1-(\frac45)^n)$, assuming $a_0=0$.

Comment: @M.Vinay Fixed, I think?

Comment: how would you go about getting $800(1-(\frac45)^n)$ from the function that I posted without using Wolfram Alpha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you playing in 1D?  If so, you are a flop.  If not, you need to consider velocity in two dimensions.  Now you need velocities in two directions.

As columbus says, you can write your equation as $a_n=0.8a_{n-1}+160$  This is an inhomogeneous [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)  If you set $b_n=a_n-800$ it becomes $b_n=0.8b_{n-1}$, which is homogeneous.  The solution is $b_n=0.8^nb_0$, so the solution to the original equation is $a_n=0.8^n(a_0-800)+800$

Comment: What? It could be a 2D platformer. As far as horizontal velocity goes, that's one dimension.

Comment: Then you need to define how the dimensions interact.  The simple one is that acceleration is capped in magnitude, so $x$ acceleration reduces the $y$ acceleration available, but you haven't said that.  I suspect it is fuzzy thinking.

Comment: Horizontal and vertical velocity are completely independent. (There's a horizontal velocity cap and a vertical velocity cap.)

Comment: I hope you are using the [Manhattan metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).  Your velocities need to correspond to distances.  Otherwise you have a crazy world but maybe your players don't care.

Comment: The horizontal component of the velocity vector and the vertical component are independent. You learn this is any course on physics, vectors, or game programming. (You know what "horizontal component" means, yes?)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: they are independent in terms of dynamics, but often the system has a limit on total acceleration. We are expressing the same truth in orthogonal axes.  I hope OP understands.

Comment: There is no acceleration cap, but there is a velocity cap. (This just has to do with the game design. If the velocity gets too high, it's hard for the computer to handle.)

Comment: @RossMillikan: This question is about velocity in one dimension, but that does not limit the world to 1D. There could still be 2 or 3 total dimensions. However, as columbus is saying, the velocities in the various dimensions are independent, so we calculate 1 dimension at a time. Position of the character is adjusted at each frame based on multiple velocities, but in a separate step for each dimension. Even with position, each dimension is handled independently. What is this multi-dimension acceleration cap you are talking about?

Comment: Often your vehicle has a certain acceleration it can make, but can make it in any direction.  If it is accelerating in $x$ as much as possible, it cannot accelerate in $y$ at all.  If it is accelerating at $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ of the maximum in $x$ it can do that much in $y$

Comment: I don't see why you would ever want to create such a limitation. Can you give an example of this? Is this related to real world physics or just something you'd expect to find in a game?

Comment: Yes, it is related to real world physics.  There is nothing special about the axes, so you shouldn't be able to accelerate more than, say, 0.5 g in any direction.  If you simultaneously acclerate 0.5 g North and 0.5 g East, you are accelerating 0.7 g Northeast.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at... If I ignore this limitation, then I could accelerate faster if I'm moving at an angle than if I'm going straight, because the hypotenuse of a right triangle is longer than either side. Come to think of it, in many games I've played (GoldenEye, Halo) you can move faster if you move diagonally... This explains why.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.  In the real world, it is truth.  In a game, you get to define how physics works in that world. My education is physics, which explains the bias.  We are taught (I believe correctly) that the axes are arbitrary and nothing real can depend on their orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_0=0,a_n = \frac45a_{n-1} + 160$. Now notice that by repeated substitution,
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac45a_{n-1} + 160
\\&=\left(\frac45\right)^2a_{n-2} + 160+\frac45\cdot160
\\&=\left(\frac45\right)^3a_{n-3}+160+\frac45\cdot160+\left(\frac45\right)^2\cdot160
\\&=\left(\frac45\right)^na_0+160\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac45\right)^k
\\&=800\left(1-\left(\frac45\right)^n\right)
\end{align}$$